# How to do regex (or text) search in multiple objects in a document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My MongoDB document has structure like below:

```
{
  "sentence 0":{
              "chunk":["some text",
                     "text",
                     "abc"]
             },  
  "sentence 1":{
              "chunk":["some text",
                     "this is a perfect thing",
                     "abc"]
             }
}
```

I need to find all the documents which have word "perfect" in `chunk` of any `sentence X`.

So far I got this, which is wrong as it doesn't even search inside all `sentence` fields.

```
db.collection.find({"Sentence 0":{ $elemMatch: {"$regex": ".*perfect.*"}}}).limit(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are **not** arrays and therefore [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) does not apply, since it's only use is with actual arrays and also for "multiple" criteria instead of one condition.

They are in fact "sub-documents" specified by "key". Your path therefore needs to be exact:

```
db.collection.find({ "sentence 1.chunk": { "$regex": ".perfect." }})
```

If you want both "paths" you need an [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/):

```
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    { "sentence 0.chunk": { "$regex": ".perfect." }},
    { "sentence 1.chunk": { "$regex": ".perfect." }}
  ]
})
```

In order to do that "without" specific paths you do the query in JavaScript logic using [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/):

```
db.collection.find(function() {
  return Object.keys(this).filter(k => /^sentence/).some(k => {
    return this[k].chunk.some(ch => /.*perfect.*/)
  })
})
```

Either case is pretty horrible since you are searching with a [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) that is not "anchored" with the caret `^` for the beginning of the string. As such a "full collection scan" is performed in order to match as opposed to using any available index. The same constraint applies to [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/).

The structure therefore is not great. Instead you should be using "real arrays" which can represent a "consistent path" to the data to search:

```
{
  "sentences": [
    {
      "chunk": [ "some text",
                 "text",
                 "abc"
      ]
    },  
      "chunk": [ "some text",
                 "this is a perfect thing",
                 "abc"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then we can actually at least create an index and query at a specific path:

```
db.collection.find({
   "sentences.chunk": { "$regex": "^some" }
})
```

Or for "real words"  then actually use a text index on `"sentences.chunk"` and search that way in an efficient manner using [`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)

```
db.collection.find({
  "$text": {
    "$search": "something"
  }
})
```

But of course that does not match things like `"the"` or `"and"` because of how text search works.

It all depends on your "real" use case. But you should at the very least avoid structuring documents using "named keys" which have "specific paths" since they are inherently bad for query purposes.

**N.B** Spaces in key names is also bad practice. It might seem "human readable", but you are asking a "machine" to read it more than you are asking a "human" do understand it. Label names are a separate thing to how you structure data.

Comment: Thanks, but the number of sentences is not just limited to two. I showed just two as an example. And the structure is a legacy system with more than 200 Billion docs, I really cannot change the structure of all the docs.

Comment: @Watt I kind of get that  you know. That's why I actually gave you "multiple options" here. Named keys are "bad news". Read all the answer and hopefully learn and understand why. And with 200 Billion, you'd [*"better get a bigger boat"*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=We%27re%20Gonna%20Need%20a%20Bigger%20Boat) and actually change the schema, since as I describe the performance of `$where` here is terrible. But your **only** option if you do not change.

Comment: sounds good :), thanks for multiple options. I will see what I can do to convince others. I will try it out and accept the answer. Thanks again.